# The counter doesn't change its value in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I've put `playerScore` and `computerScore` variables in global scope. When user wins or loses these values increment by one number. They do work well. But in my HTML page they do not change dynamically.
Why my `playerScore` and `computerScore` values do not change in my HTML page, when I console.log them separately in console they are changed, but not in html page. I've tried to put them in function but it didn't work as expected.

```
// Selecting all the items with tag button
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// Returns random item and assignes it to computerSelection variable
function computerPlay() {
    const rps = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    let numberItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * rps.length);
    computerSelection = rps[numberItem];
    if (computerSelection === 'rock') {
        console.log('computer selections is rock');
        return computerSelection;
    } 
    else if (computerSelection === 'paper' ) {
        console.log('It is a paper!');
        return computerSelection;
    }  
    console.log('it is scissors');
    return computerSelection;
}

// Plays game only five rounds;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

if(playerScore < 5 && computerScore < 5 ) {
    if(((playerSelection == 'rock') && (computerSelection == 'paper')) || ((playerSelection == 'paper') && (computerSelection == 'scissors')) || 
    ((playerSelection == 'scissors') && (computerSelection == 'rock') )) {
        console.log(`${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection} the ROBOT WINS!`);
        playerScore++;
        return console.log(playerScore);
    } 
    else if (((playerSelection == 'rock') && (computerSelection == 'scissors')) || ((playerSelection == 'paper') && (computerSelection == 'rock')) || 
    ((playerSelection == 'scissors') && (computerSelection == 'paper'))) {
        console.log(` ${playerSelection}  beats ${computerSelection} the PLAYER WINS!`);
        computerScore++;
        return console.log(computerScore);
    }
    return console.log('It is a DRAW');;
    
} 

return console.log("GAME OVER!!!");
}

// returns value of clicked button and plays round
function fetchButtonValue(e) {
    let itemClicked = e.target.dataset.item;
    console.log(` THIS WAS CLICKED ${itemClicked}`);
    return playRound(itemClicked, computerPlay());
} 

// uses fetchButtonValue 
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', fetchButtonValue);
});

// implement the vlaues to HTML but they doesn't change but the value changes when tracking them in console of browser. 

let score= `
<p class = 'playerPoints'>Player: ${playerScore}</p>
<p class = 'computerPoints'>Computer: ${computerScore}</p>
`;

const divScore = document.querySelector('.score');
divScore.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', scoreHTML);
```

Comment: are you using a reactive framework or plain js and html?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! html elements do not dynamically change when variables change they stay as they are. you will need to update the element each time you change the variables

Comment: I am using vanilla JS